# Finding upper bound for $e^2$ given E(X)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not sure how I can find the upper bound for $P(X^2 \ge 900)$ if I am given $E(X) = 20$ and $SD(X) = 4$. I am given that X is not necessarily non-negative.  I found the $E(X^2)$ = 416 I am thinking of using Chebyshev's Inequality, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Markov's inequality $P(X^{2}\geq 900) \leq \frac {EX^{2}} {900}=\frac {416} {900}$.

Comment: To the OP, this is Markov's Inequality

Comment: Would I be able to use the Markov's Inequality for this if it is stated that X is not necessarily non-negative?

Comment: @Vickie Markov's in equality is applied not to $X$ but to the new random variable $Y=X^{2}$ which is non-negative.

Answer (score 3):

$X^2 > 900 \iff X>30 \text{ or }X < -30$

$30 = 20+\frac52\cdot 4$

So Chebyshev's inequality says $\mathbb P(X>30 \text{ or }X < 10) \lt \frac{4}{25} = 0.16$ and this is also an upper bound for $\mathbb P(X>30 \text{ or }X < -30) = \mathbb P(X^2>900)$

It is tighter than the $\frac{416}{900} \approx 0.4622$ from Markov's inequality